# How to boot Ubuntu 14.04 from usb on Zenbook UX31A?

Tags: boot, live-usb, laptop, asus

I have created a bootable usb of ubuntu 14 and I know it works because it works on another laptop.
I just received an Asus zenbook UX31A with windows 8 on it.
I disabled quick boot and secure boot in the bios menu (newest Bios). 
when I attempt to boot from the USB, it boots straight into windows with no dialogue of any kind.

Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX31A
Ubuntu: 14.04
Dual-boot: Windows 8

Comment: Have a look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported

Comment: Have you find any answer yourself? Is the current answer sufficient here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with that model but please check BIOS setup again for these things:
1) Boot order 
2) Something like "Allow displaying boot choice menu" or similar. 
3) Pay attention also if there is possibly any choice like "allow booting from other/external media".

To really switch off you may need to press power switch more than 5 seconds continuous.
Sometimes last resource if everything else fails: Battery out and back to place to make sure there is not some small piece of software still running which will autoboot Windows only.

Answer (score 0):

The boot is different in Zenbooks than many other laptops like Lenovos/... Press `Esc` or `F2` during the very beginning of system startup to get to choose the boot option. Choose then the USB. If this does not work, boot to Bios and put USB first in the boot order. Please, let me know if you need more clarifications.